# Copy data in any column order

Tags: vba

The below code copies data from sheet 1(Input) and pastes the data into sheet 2(Output), the column headings in sheet 2 can be in any order and the data copies over. Good Stuff. The issues is if one of the columns in sheet1(Input) is blank with no data, it will copy the column heading into sheet 2 in the cell underneath the headings, e.g A2. I've tried editing the code by moving the rngSourceHeaders around but it still happens. Any ideas?

```
Sub CopyDataSpecificHeadings()
Dim intErrCount As Integer

'Set Data/Copy Sheets
 Dim shtSource As Worksheet: Set shtSource = Sheets("Input")
 Dim shtTarget As Worksheet: Set shtTarget = Sheets("Output")

'Create Range Objects
 Dim rngSourceHeaders As Range: Set rngSourceHeaders = shtSource.Range("A1:Z1") 'Full range of 
 the report you are looking up from

 With shtTarget
    Dim rngTargetHeaders As Range: Set rngTargetHeaders = .Range("A1:Z1") '.Cells(1, 1), 
   .Cells(1,.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)) 'Or just .Range("A1:AZ1")
    Dim rngPastePoint As Range: Set rngPastePoint = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1) 'Shoots up from the bottom of the sheet untill it bumps into something and steps one down
 End With

Dim rngDataColumn As Range

'Process Data
 Dim cl As Range, i As Integer
 For Each cl In rngTargetHeaders ' loop through each cell in target header row

'Identify source location
 i = 0 ' reset I
On Error Resume Next ' ignore errors, these are where the value can't be found and will be 
tested later
    i = Application.Match(cl.Value, rngSourceHeaders, 0) 'Finds the matching column name
On Error GoTo 0 ' switch error handling back off

'Report if source location not found
 If i = 0 Then
    intErrCount = intErrCount + 1
    Debug.Print "unable to locate item [" & cl.Value & "] at " & cl.Address ' this reports to 
    Immediate Window (Ctrl + G to view)
    GoTo nextCL
End If

'Create source data range object
 With rngSourceHeaders.Cells(1, i)
    Set rngDataColumn = Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(1000000, 1).End(xlUp))
End With

'Pass to target range object
cl.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rngDataColumn.Rows.Count, rngDataColumn.Columns.Count).Value = 
rngDataColumn.Value

nextCL:
Next cl
'Confirm process completion and issue any warnings
If intErrCount = 0 Then
  MsgBox "Process Completed", vbInformation
Else
MsgBox "WARNING: " & intErrCount & " issues encountered. Check VBA log for details", 
vbExclamation
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I think maybe it's because with this line `Set rngDataColumn = Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(1000000, 1).End(xlUp))` ---> if there's no data, then the row of rngDataColumn result is row 1 (so the rngDataColumn value is the header name). So maybe before you pass the rngDataColumn value to cl.Offset(1, 0) ... you check first, something like `if rngDataColumn.row <> 1 then` next line ...  `cl.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rngDataColumn.Rows.Count, rngDataColumn.Columns.Count).Value = 
rngDataColumn.Value` ... next line : `end if`

Comment: Thanks man, that works now. Such a simple solution. Thanks for taking the time to help.